# How to get list of documents checked out by me in view?

Tags: 2013, document-library, view, caml, check-out

I have created a document library definition in which I want to insert a view that shows all documents which are checked out by me.

The declarative code is:

```
<View BaseViewID="140" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="CheckedOutView" DefaultView="FALSE" MobileView="FALSE" MobileDefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/dlicon.png?rev=23" Url="Forms/Checkedout.aspx" Hidden="FALSE">
   <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>         
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit>20</RowLimit>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Created"/>
      </OrderBy>
      <Where>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser"/>
          <Value Type="Integer">
            <UserID Type="Integer"/>
          </Value>
        </Eq>
  </View>
```

Now what query should I write to list all documents that are checked out by me?

The reason behind achieving this by creating view is because I found one comment [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8041c293-b16a-4c46-9c0a-79040f054d4a/list-of-checked-out-documents-by-various-users?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy).
I created the view with the condition by UI and copied the declarative code by opening that view using SharePoint Designer. But not working in my case.

Comment: your CAML query is not valid, you are missing `</Where>` tag
Also answer by bcastilho is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having results with this query, please try it:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" LookupId="TRUE"/><Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value></Eq></Where>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the VM available right now. But you could try the following:

Create the view from UI and then open the view by using [SharePoint manager](https://spm.codeplex.com/). Copy the query which is generated and then use it in your XML definition.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following query helps:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser"/><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer"/></Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

Comment: I tried this query but output displays nothing. :-(

Comment: It worked for me. something else must be wrong..  :(